# Tag synonyms - [gear] and [equipment]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think these two are close enough to merit a synonym, anyone object to [gear](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear)->[equipment](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment)?

Comment: Which direction should the synonym go?

Comment: @jrdioko I was thinking the direction of my arrow, equipment is main, gear is a synonym

Answer (score 8):

I agree it should be a synonym.